# Access slow launch from .accdb, but not from within Access application

Tags: performance, ms-access, launch

This just started happening for no good reason I can find.

- If I launch the MSACCESS.EXE program, then open a database. The database opens within 1 second.
- If I launch the same database by double-clicking on the .accdb file's icon. It takes about 40 seconds for the Access window to appear, and less than 1 second after that the database opens.

The database is local, and both Access and the DB are on an SSD.  The system is an Asus Z97 motherboard, i7-4790K @ 4MHz (not overclocked) with 32gb RAM and about 200gb of free hard disk space.

In both cases, performance *after* opening is excellent with no issues. It appears it's only the launching of MSACCESS.EXE by double-clicking a .accdb file that is affected.  I double-checked the file association for .accdb and it points to the correct executable.

I captured some data with Performance Monitor during the 40-second pause. MSACCESS.EXE is using about 0.4% CPU, doing almost no disk I/O, and there's no network activity.

I've already tried "Compact and Repair" but that had no effect.

This just started happening, and now seems to be affecting Access on ALL .accdb files. They open instantly from within Access but take 40 seconds to open when double-clicked.  I haven't installed any new software or Windows updates recently.

Curiously, if I change the .accdb extension to .accdr (runs the db in the client runtime instead of full Access) the database will launch instantly.

What could possibly be going on here?  I've searched the web and found some posts having to do with databases on a network share, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Most likely, Access looks for a (default) folder on a drive or network share that no longer exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else encountering this issue, it appears this bug has nothing to do with Access specifically.

I needed to shutdown the machine, and when I did so, Windows seemed to completely ignore multiple shutdown requests.  As I was googling to troubleshoot, after about 10 minutes, the shutdown did finally start.  It took another 10 minutes to shutdown.

After rebooting the slow launch problem no longer occurs, there's only about a 2 second delay, which I assume is just MSACCESS.EXE loading "cold".

So, the problem is most likely in Windows and not Access.

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages looking for the answers to this on various sites but eventually cobbled together my own fix, so hopefully this saves others some time.

This worked for me and reduced the load time from circa 4 minutes - even just opening a blank accdb fle - to seconds... So 4 mins if double-clicking an accdb. Once MS Access open and using File | Open it was fast.

I had two instances of MS Access both on Windows Servers that can see the Internet but goes through a corporate proxy etc.

After getting some hints by Googling this issue I suspected that the 4 mins or so was some sort of timeout trying to access a site or sites (MS Office apps do this) and that eventually when the proxy returned a timeout then Access started responding again. It was quick on the 2nd open because it didn't redo this request.

Based on this, I tried to divert certain sites to 127.0.0.1 and turn off all the Internet options in Trust Centre | Privacy etc. Nothing worked.

Finally, I got the solution. In Windows Defender firewall I created a new Application rule for the MSACCESS.EXE. This was an outbound rule that blocked all Internet traffic. After this the first double-click was fast again. I assume with traffic totally blocked, whatever request is going out to sites, is immediately stopped and returns a "no internet" to Access, which then carries out executing, rather than waiting for the 3-4min timeout.